# Is the term true: $\overline{A \times B} = (\overline{A} \times \overline{B}) \cup (A \times \overline{B}) \cup (\overline{A} \times B) $?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to convert the term $\overline{A \times B}$ to a term without the complement above the whole term. I only allowed to use $\overline{A} , \overline{B}, A,B,\cup, \cap $ and $ \times$. So is this a valid conversion: $ (\overline{A} \times \overline{B}) \cup (A \times \overline{B}) \cup (\overline{A} \times B) $?

Comment: I think that this is true

Comment: What is the universe you're complementing with respect to? For example, the number $42$ is not in $A\times B$ (because $42$ is not an ordered pair at all), so it should be in $\overline{A\times B}$ -- but I don't see it on the left-hand side.

Answer (score 1):

If $$(a,b)\in \overline{A\times B}$$ then

1. either $a\not \in A$ and $b\not\in B$  that is $(a,b)\in \overline A\times \overline B$
2. or $a\not \in A$ and $b\in B$ then $(a,b)\in\overline A\times B$
3. or $a \in A$ and $b\not\in B$ then $(a,b)\in\ A\times \overline B$

So,
$$(a,b)\in \overline A\times \overline B \cup \overline A\times B \cup A\times \overline B.$$

If

$$(a,b)\in \overline A\times \overline B \cup \overline A\times B \cup A\times \overline B$$

then... (the same list of cases as above) yielding that $$(a,b)\not \in A\times B.$$

Answer (score 1):

It seems true, You can see it also using drawings [image]